# Decoding nonbreaking space in pandas read_html

Tags: python, pandas

The default behavior of `pandas.read_html` appears to be to convert `&nbsp;` characters to unicode `\xa0` codes:

```
url = 'http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/company-officers/IBM'
ibm = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
ibm.iloc[0,0]
```

> 'Virginia\xa0Rometty'

I know I can use a converter to convert these to spaces as follows:

```
spacer = lambda s: s.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
ibm = pd.read_html(url, header=0, converters={'Name':spacer})[0]
ibm.iloc[0,0]
```

> 'Virginia Rometty'

This seems unnecessarily complicated for something that must be a pretty common. Is there another way? Perhaps an `encoding` option?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think an encoding option will fix this, but you can just get rid of them. Using `str.replace`, you can get rid of any non-ASCII and replace it with a space.

```
ibm['Name'] = ibm['Name'].str.replace('[^\x00-\x8F]', ' ')
```

Or, just the non-breaking space -

```
ibm['Name'] = ibm['Name'].str.replace('\xa0', ' ')
```